# How to set my Airflow DAG to run only 1 task at a time

Tags: python, airflow

Python3, Airflow 2.2.2

I have several Airflow DAGs I use for my data pipeline. The main DAG ("rollups") consists of tons of SQL queries that get executed against my Postgres instance. Given the nature of my dependencies, the DAG is "wide" (i.e., there are a lot of sibling tasks that do not depend on one another).

Airflow's default behavior is to run all tasks that have had their dependencies fulfilled immediately, regardless of other independent tasks currently running in the DAG. That means I often end up in situations where 5-10 tasks are running at once. This overloads my small Postgres instance, which gets locked up.

I want to "force" my rollups DAG to run exactly 1 task at a time. I have accomplished this by making all my tasks sequentially dependent (B << A, C << B, etc.). However, this approach results in a super "deep" tree, and doesn't capture the logical dependencies between the tasks. If possible, I would like to make the dependency structure actually follow the logical flow of things, but force Airflow to only execute 1 task at a time.

Is this possible? Default args such as `concurrency` and `max_active_tasks_per_dag` do not seem to work (my rollups DAG still ends up running multiple tasks simultaneously).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked a [Pools](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-pools)? Limiting task concurrency/parallelism is exactly why Pools are available. Classic examples are limiting API requests and database calls.

You can create an arbitrary number of Pools with any number of slots and then assign tasks to a Pool. Airflow comes with a "default"` Pool of 128 slots (which all tasks use by default).

You could create a Pool with a slot count of 1 and assign your "rollup" tasks to this Pool. This will ensure only 1 "rollup" task executes at any given time even across DAG Runs.